# An open source Facebook app. for a valid cause :)

Tags: php, facebook

I own a couple of pages against Child abuse and now I'm developing a Facebook application for fighting against Child Abuse.

I'm somewhat a newbie, and I found many wonderful resources on the net, however, I don't seem to find what I really want.

I know to build a basic app that accesses a user's basic information(using fb_sig_user). However, I need the code to publish static content to my users' wall, request permissions for the same, (would be nice if it publishes each time they interact with my page).

It would also be nice if the app can post to the user's friends too..but its not a must.

Can someone help me? I have these files with me (its an FBML app,btw) and I'm stuck :

**tab.php**

```
<?php
 if (isset($_REQUEST['name'])){
$uidc2 = $_REQUEST['fb_sig_user'];
echo $uidc2;

?>

<div id="update"></div>
<form action="" id="frm_test" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
 <input type="hidden" name="name" size="50" />
 <input name="name" type="button" clickrewriteurl='http://somewebsite.com/fb/tab.php' clickrewriteform='frm_test' clickrewriteid='update' value="submit"/>
</form>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

require 'facebook.php';

$app_id = 'xyzzy';
$application_secret = 'abc';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $app_id,
  'secret' => $application_secret,
  'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support
));

if ($facebook->getSession()) {
  echo '<a href="' . $facebook->getLogoutUrl() . '">Logout</a>';
  $user = $facebook->getUser();
} else {
  echo '<a href="' . $facebook->getLoginUrl() . '">Login</a>';
}

?>
```

Any help a this point is really much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Curiousity rather than technical: what's the app going to do? A viral petition, email my congressman?

Comment: yes, its more of a viral petition...like a simple msg such as "Stop child abuse" or something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can  use the [`stream.publish`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish) method to publish stream to users of your app. If you want to post to users' wall even if they are not logged in, you need to ask them for the [`publish_stream`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions) extended permission first.

**Update:**

#### Getting Permissions

To get permissions, have a look at:

- [Create Facebook PopUp Authentication Window using PHP and javascript](http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/create-facebook-popup-authentication-window-using-php-and-javascript/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+Thinkdiffnet+%28Thinkdiff.net%29)

Alternatively,

In your main config or header file , put code like this:

```
$facebook = new Facebook($appapikey, $appsecret);
$user = $facebook->require_login();

$facebook->redirect('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?
client_id=[YOUR APP ID]&
redirect_uri=[YOUR APP URL]&
scope=publish_stream, offline_access');
```

Replace `[YOUR APP ID]` with application id that you can see from application settings where you created the site in Facebook Developers section. Also replace the `[YOUR APP URL]` with your app url.

#### To Publish Steam

There is another javascript sdk method named [FB.ui](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui). Using the code you can prompt user for stream publish or share your page. Checkout streamPublish() and share() methods defination in my demo’s source code .

Have a look at this tutorial for more info:

- [Graph api & javascript base Facebook Connect tutorial](http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/graph-api-javascript-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/)

Or You can use this function to publish the steam:

```
function publish() {

    var attachment = {
        'name': 'App Name',
        'href': 'http://apps.facebook.com/someapp/', 'caption': '{*actor*} perfomed an action!!',
        'description': 'The description goes here',
        "media": [{ "type": "image", "src": "http://www.example.net/images/logo.png", "href": "http://apps.facebook.com/someapp/"}]
    };

    var action_links = [{ 'text': 'World Winner 2010', 'href': 'http://apps.facebook.com/world_winner/'}];

    Facebook.streamPublish('', attachment, action_links);
}
```

Change the settings in above function as per your requirements and call it like this when you need to publish the stream:

```
publish();
```

**More Resources:**

- [Facebook Graph API — getting access tokens](http://benbiddington.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/facebook-graph-api-getting-access-tokens/)
- [How to retrieve facebook user’s friendlist](http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/how-to-retrieve-facebook-users-friendlist/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+Thinkdiffnet+%28Thinkdiff.net%29)
- [How to get mutual friends in facebook](http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/how-to-get-mutual-friends-in-facebook/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+Thinkdiffnet+%28Thinkdiff.net%29)

And you can find good facebook-related tutorials at this site:

- [thinkdiff.net](http://thinkdiff.net)

Comment: @imaginonic: It depends when you want to publish the streams. Usually it is sent upon some action like clicking on a link or when accessing the app. It is up to you when you want to publish it.

Comment: Sorry to trouble you Sarfraz..but..I would be grateful if you can let me know how I can

1) request for "publish_stream"
2) automatically publish to a user's wall after getting the permission for the same

Thank you

Comment: @imaginonic: I will be right back after an hour, got to go for some urgent task. Will come back and answer that if there are no more answers :)

Comment: Thank you, will be waiting :)

Comment: @imaginonic: For some light reading, whilst @Sarfraz is busy, check out the Facebook Authentication Page - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ - specifically the section titled "Requesting Extended Permissions", as there is something there about "publish_stream" access.

Comment: A special thanks goes to Safraz for his wonderful help, thank you very much, you rock :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check out https://github.com/brennannovak/codeigniter-facebook-oauth which lets you upload a CodeIgniter setup with a basic example application. It replaces the old php-sdk.

Comment: Did it work out ok? I have a newer version of the software if you need help with it -

Comment: I haven't checked it yet, but yes of course it would really help if you could share it :)